# AngularJS 2 route unit testing, login navigation route test

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, angular

I am writing unit test for testing the route, I have a login page with login button, I want to test that on click of my login button the page should navigate to dashboard page, but I am not sure how to do it.

here is few lines of code

```js
import {
  provide, DirectiveResolver, ViewResolver
}
from 'angular2/core';
import {
  describe, expect, it, xit, inject, beforeEachProviders, beforeEach, injectAsync, TestComponentBuilder, setBaseTestProviders
}
from 'angular2/testing';
import {
  TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
}
from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';

import {
  Router, RouterOutlet, RouterLink, RouteParams, RouteData, Location, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT
}
from 'angular2/router';
import {
  RootRouter
}
from 'angular2/src/router/router';
import {
  RouteRegistry
}
from 'angular2/src/router/route_registry';
import {
  SpyLocation
}
from 'angular2/src/mock/location_mock';

import {
  LoginComponent
}
from '../js/login.component';
import {
  EnterpriseSearchComponent
}
from '../js/enterprise-search.component';
import {
  AppConfig
}
from '../js/services/appconfig';

describe('login component', () => {
  var location, router;

  beforeEachProviders(() => {
    return [
      TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS,
      provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {
        useValue: EnterpriseSearchComponent
      }),
      provide(Router, {
        useClass: RootRouter
      }), RouteRegistry,
      provide(Location, {
        useClass: SpyLocation
      }), AppConfig
    ]
  });

  beforeEach(inject([Router, Location], (r, l) => {
    router = r;
    location = l;
  }));

  it('Should be able to navigate to Login page', (done) => {
    router.navigate(['Login']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('/login');
      done();
    }).catch(e => done.fail(e));
  });

  it('should validate login', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(LoginComponent).then((fixture) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      let instance = fixture.componentInstance;

      compiled.querySelector("#userid").value = 'dummyid';
      compiled.querySelector("#passwrd").value = 'dummypassword';
      fixture.detectChanges();

      compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      instance = fixture.componentInstance;


      compiled.querySelector("#loginbtn").click();
      fixture.detectChanges();


      // here is where i want to test that the page is navigated to dashboard screen


    });
  }));

});
```

in the above code sample, inside last test spec I want to test the navigation

Answer (score 0):

```
const element = fixture.nativeElement;
                fixture.detectChanges();
                expect(element.querySelectorAll('.dashboard-title')).toBe('Dashboard');
```

or a more clean way in my opinion is to

put your fixture into a field first i.e

```
 return tcb.createAsync(LoginComponent).then((fixture) => {
            this.myFixture = fixture;
...
```

Then you can validate it inside a different "it case" that if that page contains a specific element that only your dashboard page have

```
it('is this the login page?', () => {
            const element = this.myFixture.nativeElement;
            this.myFixture.detectChanges();
            expect(element.querySelectorAll('.dashboard-title')).toBe('Dashboard');
        });
```

Comment: I don't have such title on page, but my goal is to test it using URI, like - http://localhost:3000/dashboard, I should be able to get location.path() as 'dashboard'

Comment: I am using phantomjs to execute my unit test case, I get following output when I use 'window.location.pathname'  : /context.html. And when I use 'browser().location().url()' I am getting error browser is undefined, since I need to import it from some library.